# How to resample secondwise data to minwise data with Cassandra and GO?

Tags: go, cassandra

Disclaimer: Sorry for the long question. I have no idea how to handle the situation. I tried multiple ways but none works.

I have a Cassandra table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE democassendra.tld2 (
id1 int,
id2 int,
year int,
month int,
day int,
hour int, 
min int, 
timestamp bigint,
price int,
PRIMARY KEY ((id1, id2, year, month, day, hour, min), timestamp)
)
```

Every second, new rows are inserted into the table and every minute I want to resample them to minute-wise data.
Consider how the destination table would look like:

```
CREATE TABLE democassendra.trd2 (
id1 int,
id2 int,
year int,
month int,
day int,
hour int, 
min int, 
open int,
high int,
low int,
close int,
PRIMARY KEY ((id1, id2, year, month, day, hour, min))
)
```

I want to write a GO code that performs these tasks every minute:

- Read the rows of last minute (ideally by filtering on year, month, day, hour, min)
- Resample the data based on (id1, id2, year, month, day, hour, min).
- i.e. the seconds data for a given combination of the above attributes should be processed together.
- OHLC should be calculated as the first value, the highest value, the lowest value, and the last value of price from the given set of seconds data.
- Do this for all combinations of (id1, id2, year, month, day, hour, min).
- Send the new calculated rows to the destination table of Cassandra.

E.g:
Source:

```
id1    | id2    | year    | month    | day    | hour    | min    | timestamp (epoch)| price
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1      | 1      | 2023    | 7        | 20     | 15      | 2      | 123456           | 100
1      | 1      | 2023    | 7        | 20     | 15      | 2      | 123457           | 103
1      | 1      | 2023    | 7        | 20     | 15      | 2      | 123458           | 101
2      | 1      | 2023    | 7        | 20     | 15      | 2      | 123456           | 67
2      | 1      | 2023    | 7        | 20     | 15      | 2      | 123458           | 69
```

The destination would look like:

```
id1 | id2 | year | month | day | hour | min | OPEN| HIGH | LOW | CLOSE
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1   | 1   | 2023 | 7     | 20  | 15   | 2   | 100 | 103  | 100 | 101 
2   | 1   | 2023 | 7     | 20  | 15   | 2   | 67  | 69   | 67  | 69
```

I am able to write the piece of code which connects to Cassandra's keyspace, triggering a piece of code each minute.
I also know how to read (based on all partition keys) and write to the Cassandra table.

The problem is I cannot come up with the logic of reading Cassandra, resampling it.

My initial logic was at every minute,

- read all rows which belonged to a given (year, month, day, hour, min).
- Then (somehow) for all combinations of (id1, id2, year, month, day, hour, min) read all rows and calculate OHLC.
- send it to the destination table.

But I can't even perform the first step as Cassandra doesn't allow reading based on a part of the partition key. I can only do filtering when all the partition key is used.

I am new to both GO and Cassandra.

I understand this is a big problem and can require a lot of time but your help would be greatly appreciated.